# What does JOLT [&] syntax means?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I've read [this](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/shiftr/arrayExample.json) and [this](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java) and [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350) but explanations are pretty scarce.
I understand what "&" means. But I can't wrap my head around what [&] means =\

Can someone please explain me what this [&] does applicable to this example?
What exactly happening in lines

```json
"@1": "outer[&4].inner[&2].t",
"@(3,eventTypeCode)": "outer[&4].inner[&2].etc"
```

**Input JSON** :

```json
{
  "uID": 1000358546,
  "events": [
    {
      "eventTypeCode": "FEEDBACK",
      "transports": [
        "PUSH",
        "SMS"
      ]
    },
    {
      "eventTypeCode": "MARKETING",
      "transports": [
        "PUSH",
        "EMAIL"
      ]
    },
    {
      "eventTypeCode": "ORDER_STATUS",
      "transports": [
        "SOC_VK"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "events": {
        "*": {
          "transports": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@1": "outer[&4].inner[&2].t",
                "@(3,eventTypeCode)": "outer[&4].inner[&2].etc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

**Result** :

```json
{
  "uID": 1000358546,
  "outer": [
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "t": "PUSH",
          "etc": "FEEDBACK"
        },
        {
          "t": "SMS",
          "etc": "FEEDBACK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "t": "PUSH",
          "etc": "MARKETING"
        },
        {
          "t": "EMAIL",
          "etc": "MARKETING"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "t": "SOC_VK",
          "etc": "ORDER_STATUS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count the **single colon**(*colon without opening curly brace*) along with the other **opening curly braces** while going the tree up(from *inner* to *outer*) for any wildcard such as `@`,`$`,`&`,`[&]`. Only difference among **`&`** and **`[&]`** is the second one tries to build an array while the first one replicates the respective value of the targeted level. So, **`[&]`** would do nothing(*doesn't build an array*) whenever the ampersand fully points out null values unlike to **`&`**

A side note : **`key[&]`** yields (with/without a dot after *key*) key name of the array while **`key&`** yields a simple concatenation (prefixing the respective value of **`&`**)

Let me try to explain using this spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "events": {
        "*": {
          "transports": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@1": "@(4,eventTypeCode).[&2]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

you'd get the result

```json
{
  "FEEDBACK" : [ "PUSH", "SMS" ],
  "MARKETING" : [ "PUSH", "EMAIL" ],
  "ORDER_STATUS" : [ "SOC_VK" ]
}
```

by using the above spec.

but it would yield

```json
{
  "FEEDBACK" : {
    "0" : "PUSH",
    "1" : "SMS"
  },
  "MARKETING" : {
    "0" : "PUSH",
    "1" : "EMAIL"
  },
  "ORDER_STATUS" : {
    "0" : "SOC_VK"
  }
}
```

- if **`[&2]`** is replaced with **`&2`**. Since, both reaches to the
  same level(*the level of the indices of "transports" through counting
  0->[traversing single colon], 1->[traversing opening curly brace],
  2->[traversing opening curly brace]* ), one makes array while the
  other reveals the values of the indices as 0,1. Think a reciprocally
  changing for the represented values by `"@1"` and
  `"@(4,eventTypeCode)"`(*right hand side one goes left while left hand
  side one goes right*) -> `@1` picks the values of the indices of
  "transports"(traversing opening curly brace twice by counting 0,1[if
  it was `@`[meaning @0] would traverse `{` once by counting only 0).
- if **`[&2]`** is replaced with **`&`**, then the output would be
  replicating the values coming from `@1`; while if **`[&2]`** is
  replaced with **`[&]`**, then there would yield only a **null**
  because the innermost node has only nulls.